# Can any charge distribution be considered as a collection of dipole distributions?"

Tags: electricity

"consider a region where there  are various type of charges but total charge is zero. At points outside the region, is the electric field due to dipole moment of charge distribution only? and would this also suggest that field due to it be proportional to $ \frac{1}{r^3}$"

This really messes with my brain because there could be like charge distributions like quadropole which has the field dropping as a inverse tetration of 'r'. but at the same time one could decompose the charge distribution into many dipoles which should give something similar to inverse cube law. What exactly would be a behaviour of a random charge distribution whose net charge is 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field around a point charge drops as $1/r^2$.

A dipole is separated + and - point charges. At a distance the fields do not quite cancel. The field drops as $1/r^3$.

You can do the same thing with 2 separated dipoles oriented in opposite directions. You can form a quadrupole where the fields do not quite cancel, and drops as $1/r^4$. You can think of the quadrupole as a quadrupole, a collection of dipoles, or a collection of point charges.

At a distance, the field of any finite distribution of charges can be decomposed into a monopole moment, dipole moment, etc. Like a Taylor series or a Fourier series, the lower terms are the most important, and higher terms tell you about details. See [Multipole expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multipole_expansion) in Wikipedia.

Comment: So are the answers to the questions no and no?

Comment: That is correct.